# Why MapReduce second job won't sort?

Tags: python, mapreduce, bigdata

I have a little problem with this code, the first job runs fine adds the sum of my prices for every customer but on the second job it should sort my prices and it does't my console still yields the first job, why?

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep


class CustomerCount(MRJob):
    def steps(self):
        return [
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_initial,
                   reducer=self.reducer_initial),
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_sort,
                   reducer=self.reducer_sort)
        ]

    def mapper_initial(self, _, line):
        (customerID, price) = line.split(',')[0:3:2]
        yield customerID, float(price)

    def reducer_initial(self, customerID, prices):
        yield customerID, sum(prices)

    def mapper_sort(self, customerID, price):
        yield '%04.02f' % float(price), customerID

    def reducer_sort(self, price, customersID):
        for val in customersID:
            yield val, price


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CustomerCount.run()
```

The line of the data looks something like this: (I'm interested in the first and second element) :

```
44,8602,37.19
35,5368,65.89
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second MR step mapper is writing price as key. Hence all customer id with same key will be sorted, but the data will not be sorted by customer id. To validate this hypothesis, try running it with couple of customer having same price.
To get the output the way you requested, you can send constant key on mapper (eg constant string "1") and write a custom comparator call to sort the price and customer ID.